# How to center a html 5 canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to center a dynamic html 5 canvas window with javascript. I know the code I have doesn't work, but I'm wondering if there's a way that implements the margin-left: auto/margin-left: auto  technique that usually centers elements within a html page. I've also tried this with my canvas class css and that does not work either so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

My code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");


document.getElementById("canvas").style.marginLeft = "auto";
document.getElementById("canvas").style.marginRight = "auto";

canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
drawScreen();

formElement = document.getElementById("height");
formElement.addEventListener('change', heightChanged, true);

formElement = document.getElementById("width");
formElement.addEventListener('change', widthChanged, false);

function widthChanged(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  canvas.width = target.value;
  drawScreen();
}

function heightChanged(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  canvas.height = target.value;
  drawScreen();
}

function drawScreen() {
}
```

Comment: you are tying to center the canvas window ?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying the center the canvas window.

Comment: why you don't use css the center it ?

Comment: If set the left and right margins to "auto" it doesn't center the canvas and I want it stay centered even if I resize it the browser window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the canvas a block-level element.  You can do so with CSS or by adding this line to your code:

```
canvas.style.display= 'block';
```

**Example:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

document.getElementById("canvas").style.marginLeft = "auto";
document.getElementById("canvas").style.marginRight = "auto";
canvas.style.display= 'block';
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
drawScreen();

formElement = document.getElementById("height");
formElement.addEventListener('change', heightChanged, true);

formElement = document.getElementById("width");
formElement.addEventListener('change', widthChanged, false);

function widthChanged(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  canvas.width = target.value;
  drawScreen();
}

function heightChanged(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  canvas.height = target.value;
  drawScreen();
}

function drawScreen() {
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<div id="height"></div>
<div id="width"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you do like so  with `css` :

```
canvas {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

or with `javascript` :

```
 document.getElementById("canvas").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("canvas").style.margin = "auto";
        document.getElementById("canvas").style.position = "absolute";
        document.getElementById("canvas").style.top = 0;
        document.getElementById("canvas").style.bottom = 0;
        document.getElementById("canvas").style.left = 0;
        document.getElementById("canvas").style.right = 0;
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n5dqcg6d/)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you put your canvas into a div container ?

you can do it via javascript too.

```
var container = document.createElement("div");
container.style.marginLeft = "auto";
container.style.marginRight = "auto";
container.style.width = "300px";

container.innerHtml = canvas;
```